# How can I achieve thread safety in an async method?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, concurrency, actor

I am trying to read the keychain but the documentation warns me about the following:

> SecItemCopyMatching blocks the calling thread, so it can cause your app’s UI to hang if called from the main thread. Instead, call SecItemCopyMatching from a background dispatch queue or async function.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching)

So I want to write an asynchronous method that runs in the background.

```
actor Keychain {
    public static let standard = Keychain()
    
    public enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case failed(String)
    }
    
    public func get(_ key: String) async throws -> Data? {
        let backgroundTask = Task(priority: .background) {
            var query: [String: Any] = [
                type(of: self).klass       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
                type(of: self).attrAccount : key,
                type(of: self).matchLimit  : kSecMatchLimitOne,
                type(of: self).returnData  : kCFBooleanTrue as CFBoolean
            ]
            
            var item: CFTypeRef?
            let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
            
            guard status == errSecSuccess else {
                if let errorMessage = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) {
                    throw Error.failed(String(errorMessage))
                } else {
                    throw Error.failed("unsupported")
                }
            }
            
            return item as? Data
        }
        return try await backgroundTask.value
    }
}
```

My question is.. will the actor already make it thread safe?

Normally I would add a `NSLock` to be safe.

```
public func get(_ key: String) async throws -> Data? {
    lock.lock()
    defer { lock.unlock() }
    
    (...)
    
    return try await task.value
}
```

However now I get a warning `Instance method 'lock' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Use async-safe scoped locking instead; this is an error in Swift 6`.

So how I am able to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actors will make it thread-safe. No need for locks or the like. See WWDC 2021 video [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).

---

BTW, since you've got this on an actor, you really don't need to make `get(_:)` an `async` method. The actor already runs on a background thread. So remove the `async` qualifier and then remove the `Task`:

```swift
actor Keychain {
    ...
    
    public func get(_ key: String) throws -> Data? {
        var query: [String: Any] = [
            type(of: self).klass       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
            type(of: self).attrAccount : key,
            type(of: self).matchLimit  : kSecMatchLimitOne,
            type(of: self).returnData  : kCFBooleanTrue as CFBoolean
        ]
        
        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
        
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            if let errorMessage = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) {
                throw Error.failed(String(errorMessage))
            } else {
                throw Error.failed("unsupported")
            }
        }
        
        return item as? Data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using all local variables (no instance or static variables) so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put Keychain operations in a async block that is not needed. You are good to go without it. Keychain operations are Thread safe and that is guaranteed by Apple. See this documentation. [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services)

So do it without the async block and put all ui changes in the main thread (if it is not already). UI changes need to be in the main thread.