# Can a property be safely accessed from async functions?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, swift5

With Swift's 5.5 async/await, can we access the same property from two different async functions?

For example, let's say you have:

```
var foobarInstance: FooBar?

func start() async {
   foobarInstance = await buildFooBar()
   ....
}

func process() async {
   if let foo = self.foobarInstance {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Is it safe to access `self.foobarInstance` that way? Does Swift handle that automatically?

Comment: I think `Actor` will help. Could you please check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210041/how-can-i-achieve-thread-safety-in-an-async-method

Comment: This depends entirely on context. If the property and the functions are within the same task, then there is inherent thread safety. If they are within separate tasks then that safety is lost. However, if they are in separate tasks but within the same actor, then the safety is regained. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/

Answer (score 3):

The `async` functions alone are not sufficient. But if both the property and the methods are actor-isolated, then, yes, you can access the same property from multiple methods. E.g.:

```swift
actor Qux {
    private var foobar: FooBar?
    
    func start() async {
        foobar = await buildFooBar()
        …
    }
    
    func process() async {
        if let foobar {
            // do something with `foobar`
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I am using an explicit `actor` type, but it also works with global actors (such as `@MainActor`).

I do not know what your `FooBar` type is, but if you ever expose it outside this actor-isolated context, you may want to make sure that it is thread-safe, too (e.g., `Sendable`). In this case, I explicitly made it `private` to ensure it was not unnecessarily exposed outside of this context.

See WWDC 2021 video [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133) and 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351).